# jQuery selecting data-href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

I am creating a Chrome extension which removes the Google Redirection when clicking on a link on a Google search. I have done an inspect element on a link and I can see that there is a function called 'onmousedown' and also a 'data-href' which is the actual link to the website. I have been able to remove the 'onmousedown'. However, I was wondering how I can make the link the 'data-href'? Sorry if this is a bit hard to understand.

Here is an image of the inspect element. Basically I want to put the `data-href` in the `a href`.

[image: Inpectect Element]

Here is what I have done so far.

```
$(document).on("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
   $("a[onmousedown]").removeAttr("onmousedown");
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function) like below to get all elements with `data-href` attribute and it that value as the value of the `href` attribute.

```
$('a[data-href]').attr('href', function () {
    return $(this).attr('data-href')
})
```

Comment: Quick reply! Thanks, it works so well. However, I can I remove the attribute 'onmousedown' as well?

Comment: @RyanHawdon your code should remove the attribute, isn't it

Comment: Also, how do I detect changes for the input box? I have done this but it isn't working.

`$("input[type='text']").change(function() {
        $("a[onmousedown]").removeAttr("onmousedown");
        $('a[data-href]').attr('href', function() {
            return $(this).attr('data-href');
        });
});`

Comment: @RyanHawdon why do you want to do that

Comment: Because I don't want to see if the whole document has been changed. I just want to do in the input box as when the user types.